# htaccess to redirect to another page if the url contains '.php'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect any pages on my site that contain a .php at the end to th home page.

Looking around online and can't find anything on how to do this.

I've tried

```
RedirectMatch "^/.*.php/?$" "https://www.website.com/home/"
```

But it doesn't seem to work, causes an infinite loop